# Read image from database and send through web service

Tags: sql-server, database, c#-4.0

I have a table in my data base that contains system users data, and one of these data is profile picture,
I'm trying to read these data and send it to smart phone using web service,

i try the following code but it didn't work

```
        public User select(string username, string password)
    {

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from users where userName = @uname and password = @pwd or email = @uname and password = @pwd");


        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", username);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", password);

        DBAccess db = new DBAccess();
        DataSet ds = db.select(myCommand);

        User user = new User();
        DataRow dr;

        try
        {                
            dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];

            user.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["userID"]);                
            user.FirstName = (string)dr["firstName"]+" ";
            user.LastName = (string)dr["lastName"] + " ";
            user.Email = (string)dr["email"] + " ";
            user.Username = (string)dr["userName"];
            user.Password = (string)dr["password"];
            user.type = (string)dr["type"];
            user.followingID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["followingID"]);
            user.theme = Convert.ToInt32(dr["theme"]);
            user.tel = (string)dr["tel"] + " ";
            user.mobile = (string)dr["mobile"] + " ";
            user.fax = (string)dr["fax"] + " ";
            user.lastLoggedIn = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["lastLoggedIn"]);
            user.image = Convert.ToByte[](dr["Image"]);

            return user;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DAO.exDao myEx = new DAO.exDao();

            return null;
        }
    }//end of select method
```

I don't know how to read image from database and save it as array of bytes in order to send throw web service, so the error on the following line

```
user.image = Convert.ToByte[](dr["Image"]);
```

Comment: Dear Fadi Khalil Please Define your Query and  where do u Want to send

Comment: my query already i defined above, and i want to read image from table called 'users' from column called 'Image' and i want to save it as array of bytes in order to send to iPhone using a web service

Answer (score 0):

You can store the path of the image in the database. Then after retrieving that you can show the image.